# Should EGL context terminated when activity goes background?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

I am writing an opengl app in native code for android using native activity. I remember that when using java with opengl, I had to use GLSurfaceView which would manage the context on its way, sometimes it would destroy it when the phone was going to idle etc.

But now I have full control of my EGL context, I can sure preserve it all the time, but is it OK ? My minimum target SDK is 9.
Is it safe to keep it until app is destroyed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving egl context, created via native code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935735/preserving-egl-context-created-via-native-code)